# summing values ​from input when clicking on button JS. Help please! deadline)

Tags: javascript, html, input

When i click on the button, add the value from the input and display the quantity of goods and the amount in span instead of XXX and XXX
there are many identical buttons and when adding another product, the amount should be added to the previous one
I will be grateful for any help)

```js
   

     
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('product-box__btn');
let input = document.getElementById('total__prods');
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        input.innerHTML = e.target.closest('.product-box__meta').querySelectorAll('.qty__item')[i].value;
    });
}
let cost = document.getElementById('total__price');
for (let i = 0; i < cost.innerText; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      cost.innerHTML = e.target.closest('.product-box__meta').querySelectorAll('.qty__item')[i].value;
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="top-cart">
        <div class="top-cart-info">
            <div class="container top-cart-info-container">
                <span class="top-cart-info__item">
                    Товаров в корзине - <span class="red-info" id="total__prods">XXX</span>,
                    на сумму <span class="red-info" id="total__price">XXX</span></span>
                <a class="btn-check" href="#openModal">Оформить заказ</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.top-cart-info -->

    </div><!-- /.top-cart -->
<div class="product-box__item">
  <h3 class="product-box__title">Овсяная каша с фруктами</h3>
  <div class="product-box__img">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="i/im1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="product-box__meta">
    <p>25 грн.</p>
    <div class="qty">
      <input class="qty__item" type="number"> Кол
    </div>
    <button class="product-box__btn" onclick="addition(this);">Добавить</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-albattani-s0snm?file=/src/index.js

Comment: How many buttons do you have? Also`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist so you can't assign a value to it.

Comment: First- you pass the string. and you have to parseInt. Second- I think innerText is better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addition() {
      let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.red-info');

        [].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
let input = document.getElementsByClassName("qty__item")[0].value;
      console.log(input);
          // do whatever
          div.innerText = input;
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="top-cart">
  <div class="top-cart-info">
    <div class="container top-cart-info-container">
      <span class="top-cart-info__item">
              Товаров в корзине - <span class="red-info">XXX</span>, на сумму
      <span class="red-info">XXX</span> грн</span>
      <a class="btn-check" href="#openModal">Оформить заказ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.top-cart-info -->
</div>
<div class="product-box__item">
  <h3 class="product-box__title">Овсяная каша с фруктами</h3>
  <div class="product-box__img">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="i/im1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="product-box__meta">
    <p>25 грн.</p>
    <div class="qty">
      <input class="qty__item" type="number"> Кол
    </div>
    <button class="product-box__btn" onclick="addition(this);">Добавить</button>

  </div>
</div>
```